# Getting series color from LineChart

Tags: colors, javafx, javafx-2, linechart, series

`LineChart` has series which have different color by default. How can I get it to set obtained color to other text connected with the specified series?

Comment: Do you want the color or the series styleclass ?

Comment: I have StackPane with LineCharts
Each Linechart has several series
I want to place *all* the legends at the bottom, but I can't. Therefore I want  to create text for each series with its color. For example, 
LineChart1 has 2 series: red and blue; LineChart2 has 2 series: orange and green.
At the bottom of the page must be 4 texts of this color: 
_series1name is red text_ &
_series2name is  blue_...
It is need to obtain color and type to set it for created text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a line chart since all elements of a single series have one color. The series are assigned with styleclass `series0`, `series1`, `series2` etc.

Each of these series are assigned with corresponding colors styleclass i.e. `default-color0`, `default-color1`, `default-color2` etc. You can directly use the styleclass for your text/labels.