# Get Line Chart Series Stroke Color

Tags: javafx, charts

this is a follow up to this question: [How to get the color from a series in JavaFX Chart and assign it to a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685073/how-to-get-the-color-from-a-series-in-javafx-chart-and-assign-it-to-a-checkbox) which has 0 answers.

I want to get my LineChart series stroke generated color, in order to set it as the text color of a checkbox.

This is my sample code (the line chart taken from Oracle tutorial):

```
public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        HBox box = new HBox();

        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        CheckBox test = new CheckBox("test");

        test.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: <series color>;");

        box.getChildren().addAll(lineChart, test);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I tried to add the series style class to the checkbox styleclass (as suggested in [Getting series color from LineChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074315/getting-series-color-from-linechart)):

```
test.getStyleClass().addAll(series.getNode().getStyleClass());
```

where the series style class is a list with the values: chart-series-line, series0, and default-color0 but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the `Update: try this!` code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380403/javafx-line-chart-change-color-shape/56380857#56380857. See if there is a getStyle method and if it returns what you need. I will look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Sedrick, series.getNode().lookup(".series0").getStyle() returns an empty string :\

Comment: Here is something to play with. Add it after `stage.show()`. `String lineStyle = String.format("-fx-stroke: %s;\n-fx-line: %s;", "#f0e68c", "#f0e68c");
        series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line").setStyle(lineStyle);
        System.out.println(series.getNode().lookup(".chart-series-line").getStyle());`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153370/how-to-set-specific-color-to-javafx-xychart-series

Comment: https://news.kynosarges.org/2017/05/14/javafx-chart-coloring/\

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I read all of these articles before posted the question. The issue is that I wanted to use the generated colors instead of defining the colors myself. I will probably use your solution since I don't think what I wanted to do is currently possible. Thanks again!